# CLion debug: lldb attach to a process, breakpoint is grey saying no executable

Tags: debugging, clion, lldb

I am trying to debug tensorflow project, which uses SWIG technique to wrap c++ implementation with python frontend. I want to debug C++ part. Here is what I did:

1. launch a tensorflow python script in terminal ($pid)
2. directly using `lldb -p $pid` works fine, I can set breakpoints, etc.
3. but I want to use CLion debug GUI, so I click `Clion->Run->Attach to Process`, find $pid as a native process.
4. CLion successfully attached to $pid, however, every breakpoint I set in Clion is grey and will not be hit. but if I set breakpoints in embedded lldb console, it works(breakpoint hits and highlight in Clion code file).

the error message on CLion breakpoint is:

> Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associate
>   with this line.

P1:
[image]
P2:
[image]

how to make this right, so that I can set breakpoints in Clion rather lldb command?

Extra information:

- tensroflow using bazel to build. I don't use Clion to build. just editing/browsing/debuging. CLion has a bazel plugin, but bind to specific bazel version, not ok for me.
- CLion version 2.19.2